# AngularJS Checkbox not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

**Edit** Some additional words to make sure that you catch the problem. On load the checkboxes have the correct status (whether checked or not) but I am not able t change them. When I click on them they should render the new status, shouldn't they? Or is there a event.preventDefault() created by Angular?

I am facing following problem.

I have a controller and a form with some checkboxes. When I click on them, nothing happens.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<article class="window__Content" ng-controller="ElementController as element">
    <label>Favorite Colors</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.red"> Red
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.blue"> Blue
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.green"> Green
        </label>
    </div>
</article>
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ElementController', [elementController]);

    function elementController(Element, WindowData){

        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.formData = {
            red: true,
            blue: false,
            green: true
        };

        activate();

        ///////////////

        function activate(){
        }

    }

})();
```

So all I want to do is to check and uncheck the checkboxes, that would be enough. Maybe anyone of you can spot a mistake.

I should add that the HTML-Snippet is included to the DOM via ng-include. Could this be a problem

Greetz
Raj

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: you want that checkboxes set true when you load the controller?

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxpfy4eo/). Maybe you just forgot no use ng-app somewhere.

Comment: Meeh, so that means that this piece is correct and the error is anywhere else in my code ... Could it be a problem that I initiate the Controller twice?  Cause when I click on my checkboxes they do not change their state ...

Comment: Have you checked if your function elementController is actually called ?

Comment: Yes, thats working well. An alert() in activate-function fires ...

Comment: Without providing a jsfiddle which reproduce the problem it will be tough to answer.

Comment: @nubinub Yes that's right, I am trying to create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem without copying my whole project ...

Answer (score 0):

i would use `ng-checked`to solve this.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d93mzqw0/1/

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ElementController">
<article class="window__Content">
<label>Favorite Colors</label>{{vm}}
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.red" ng-checked="vm.formData.red"> Red
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.blue"  ng-checked="vm.formData.blue"> Blue
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="element.formData.green" ng-checked="vm.formData.green"> Green
    </label>
</div>
</article>
</body>
```

and the js:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('ElementController', ElementController);
function ElementController($scope){

    /* jshint validthis: true */
    $scope.vm = {};
    $scope.vm.formData = {
        red: true,
        blue: false,
        green: true
    };

};
```

Comment: Your js-fiddle doesn't even work. You are missing `vm.` in the ng-models ... Another question would why you added `$scope`? Is there something wrong with the AS-Controller coding?

Comment: ? my fiddle works fine^^ `$scope` is elementary in angularJS. have a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. And `vm` is the object in the `ng-checked`...as you can read

Comment: No, you do not need $scope. You can use `this` as well. That's what I am doing with `vm` ... In your example `ng-model="element.formData.red"` muste be `ng-model="vm.element.formData.red"`... Otherwise it can't work

Comment: of course you can. why do u use angular if you don't use it oO

Comment: This post is the wrong place to discuss, but in short. AngularJS is a framework that makes you keep some conventions ... But it does give you some kind of freedom as well. But when yu start developing you should maintain a style of coding that is clean and readable ...
Have a look at this styleguide and you will understand my way of coding https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: bro rly, i have been developing with angular during the last 6 months...i know that my solution is clean, functional and pure angular. If you use it for your problem or not can just be decided by urself...i really don't want to discuss with you if my solution was clean angular or not. have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the mistake while creating a jsFiddle for you. I had an parent controller that fired an event.preventDefault() on every onclick on `<article>`-tag ...

So what did we learn? Sharing the problem makes you more intelligent than keeping it a secret :D

Thx guys!